# Mahout, PostgreSQL and connection pool

Tags: connection-pooling, mahout, pg-jdbc

Using PostgreSQL as data source in Mahout 0.9, I keep getting

`WARN org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.jdbc.AbstractJDBCDataModel - You are not using ConnectionPoolDataSource. Make sure your DataSource pools connections to the database itself, or database performance will be severely reduced.`

warning.

And it's true - each request keeps opening new connections.

Is there any way to use `PGConnectionPoolDataSource` for `PostgreSQLBooleanPrefJDBCDataModel`?

(currently I have `no constructorfor arguments n Java::OrgApacheMahoutCfTasteImplModelJdbc::PostgreSQLBooleanPrefJDBCDataModel` error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, you'll likely don't need a connections pool at all, as the right solution is to use memory-based ReloadFromJDBCDataModel wrapper, which, as the side-effect, decreases the number of connections to 1.